# How to compare a Firebase/scrypt hashed password for Basic Authentication in Firebase-admin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, bcrypt

I want to authenticate calls to our firebase-functions endpoint using a Basic authorization header that contains a uid & password.  I thought Firebase was using bcrypt, so I had planned to  use bcrypt.compare.  Is there a way to do this for whatever version of scrypt Firebase uses?  Users were created using admin.auth().createUser({...}).

I was testing the bcrypt plan with this (a known uid & password are in req.body):

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
app.post("/hash", async (req, res) => {
    const listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers();
    
    const userResult = listUsersResult.users[listUsersResult.users.findIndex((userRecord) => userRecord.uid == req.body.uid)];
    const passhash = userResult.passwordHash;

    const result = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, passhash);
    return res.status(200).send(`compare ${req.body.password} and ${passhash}: ${result}`);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just forward the request on to [Google IDP](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPassword) to confirm the password?

Comment: Additionally, **never** send back passwords in plain text nor should you send the hash of the user's actual password too - even if you are just testing.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for responding.  I was hoping to find a JS solution for the custom scrypt.  Alternatively, an extra REST call is needed OR adding the dependencies for the non-admin Firebase SDK.  Honestly, between those two, I don't know which is a better performance option.

Comment: What I meant by forwarding the call, is to make the REST call inside your function using `fetch`, you are already making an API call to list the users, so just swap it out for the auth REST API call instead - no added dependencies needed and more secure.

Comment: @samthecodingman this works great using the signInWithPassword endpoint as long as the email+password are in the Basic header, not uid+password.  Are you checking the password with a different endpoint OR requiring the email to be passed in the header?

Comment: Ah, I missed that you were passing the `uid`. Make a call to `await admin.auth().getUser(uid)` first then?

Comment: @samthecodingman thank you for your help on this.  I guess I am going to switch the client-side login to use email to streamline things.  Thank you again.

Comment: @samthecodingman , could you please post it as an answer so that it can also help the community.